# Sphere center point and radius from 3 points on the surface

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

Is it possible to find he center of sphere and its radius from 3 points on the surface ?

I'm building a model for a segmented brain structure were the three points would be within the structure; head, tail and middle.

Thank you,

Comment: Ok if the points are known to be on a great circle. Otherwise four points are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express that the center of the sphere is equidistant to the three given points and coplanar with them (assuming that the three given points are on a great circle).

```
(X - Xa)² + (Y - Ya)² + (Z - Za)² = R²    
(X - Xb)² + (Y - Yb)² + (Z - Zb)² = R²    
(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)² + (Z - Zc)² = R²    

|X  Y  Z  1|
|Xa Ya Za 1|
|Xb Yb Zb 1| = 0
|Xc Yc Zc 1|
```

Subtracting the first equation from the second and the third, you get rid of the quadratic terms.

```
(2X - Xb - Xa)(Xb - Xa) + (2Y - Yb - Ya)(Yb - Ya) + (2Z - Zb - Za)(Zb - Za) = 0
(2X - Xc - Xa)(Xc - Xa) + (2Y - Yc - Ya)(Yc - Ya) + (2Z - Zc - Za)(Zc - Za) = 0
```

Now you have an easy linear system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns.

---

For conciseness you can translate the three points so that `Xa=Ya=Za=0`, and the equations simplify as

```
|X  Y  Z |
|Xb Yb Zb| = 0
|Xc Yc Zc|

(2X - Xb) Xb + (2Y - Yb) Yb + (2Z - Zb) Zb = 0
(2X - Xc) Xc + (2Y - Yc) Yc + (2Z - Zc) Zc = 0
```

or

```
(Yb Zc - Yc Zb) X + (Zb Xc - Zc Xb) Y + (Xb Yc - Xc Yb) Z = 0
       2 Xb     X +        2 Yb     Y +        2 Zb     Z = Xb² + Yb² + Zb²
       2 Xc     X +        2 Yc     Y +        2 Zc     Z = Xc² + Yc² + Zc²
```

Then, `R² = X² + Y² + Z²`, and don't forget to translate back.

Comment: ow I see now you're right points must be on a great circle (deleted wrong answer of mine)...

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, but it will always give you a sphere which the surface input points will be on its equator (meaning there are other, larger spheres that have these 3 points on it's surface if there's a fourth not coplanar point given).

But I think the smallest sphere is what you want. The following code written in C# gives you a Vector3 with the center of the sphere. The distance can then be obtained with Vector3.Distance (or a simple pithagorean distance) between any of the input points and the resulting center.

```
static public Vector3 BarycentricToWorld3D(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, float u, float v, float w) {
    return (u * p1 + v * p2 + w * p3) / (u + v + w);
}

static public Vector3 CircleBariCenter3D(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3) {

    Vector3 a = p3 - p2;
    Vector3 b = p1 - p3;
    Vector3 c = p2 - p1;

    float u = Vector3.Dot(a, a) * Vector3.Dot(c, b);
    float v = Vector3.Dot(b, b) * Vector3.Dot(c, a);
    float w = Vector3.Dot(c, c) * Vector3.Dot(b, a);

    return BarycentricToWorld3D(p1, p2, p3, u, v, w);
}
```

Notice there's no checking for colinear points, which will make this fail. It should be trivial to add such checking by simply feeding this colinear points and watching it fail in the debugger.

Credits: I got a maxscript source for this 10+ years ago and lost the original author and location, and translated it into C# quite recently.